# C# Show a progress bar in a popup window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to have a progress bar in a popup window, while my main thread is doing some heavy calculations.
I'm using an Oracle API , all the heavy work is done calling 1 function of this API, so I can't use the backgroudworker update becasue I don't have the API's code.
I tried to create a new form with an ProgressBar and a Timer, but the timer_Click event is never fired!!(???)

Any Idea??

Comment: It's Timer_Tick() and not Timer_Click() !

Comment: What .Net version are You on ?

Comment: This question has fetched a nice answer +1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> while my main thread is doing some heavy calculations.

Wrong. Never do any heavy calculations inside your main thread in a Windows application or your users will simply hate you.

If your API doesn't provide a way to report the progress then the best you could do is show some rotating animation while the calculation is in progress because you will not be able to know the exact percentage of work done. So put the calculation inside a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx), show some spinning animation before running the calculation (which should itself be done inside the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event) and hide the animation once the work is done ([RunWorkerCompletedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx)).

The ProgressBar has a `Style` property that you could set to `Marquee` to emulate an infinite progression.

Comment: What about using a ProgressBar in a new form, with a Timer?? I dont mind reseting the progressbar to 0 once in a while

Comment: Personally I wouldn't do that because that would be cheating your users and would be IMHO bad UI design decision. But yeah, if you want to do it why not. By the way the `ProgressBar` has a `Style` property which you could set to `Marquee` to emulate an infinite progress. You don't need to use any timer. I will update my answer to include this information.

Comment: we are talking winforms. yes??

Comment: Well. I got it. Thank you. I set the Style to Marquee . It is good enough for me.